# Induction proof - Stumped as to how a certain step was achieved

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

[The proof in question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAJZD.png)

The part I've underlined is what I don't understand - where did the second (k+1) come from? Did the author make a substitution that I am not registering?

Comment: He separated out the highest term of the sum from the rest of the sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the indices of summation. On the LHS of the equation, it goes up to $k+1$, but on the RHS, it goes to $k$. The last term is brought out of the summation, which is what you underlined.

Comment: Ah, I see it. Thank you.